# BSOD when enabling on board video

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, bsod, on-board-peripheral

Machine Model: [HP Compaq 8200 Elite Convertible Minitower](http://www.cdw.ca/shop/products/HP-Compaq-Elite-8200-Core-i5-2500-3.3-GHz/2371400.aspx#TS) P/N: XZ805UT#ABA

PCIe x16 Video Card: [HP AMD Radeon HD 6570](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/amd-radeon-hd-6000/hd-6570/pages/amd-radeon-hd-6570-overview.aspx#2)

On board video: Intel HD Graphics 2000(integrated)

Operating System: Windows 7 Professional x64

When I enable the on board video in the BIOS, the machine blue screens with "IRQL LESS OR NOT EQUAL". I have tried changing the primary video device to the on board and the video card itself, no luck. When I disable the on board the blue screen doesn't happen. I checked the drivers for both cards and they are correct. I can boot into safe mode with both cards enabled which makes me think it is a driver issue. I would like to use both on board and the video card so I can use 4 monitors.

Comment: Your onboard video is Intel HD Graphics 2000 according to the Compaq specs, the number you provided is for a NIC

Comment: Yea, sorry about that. I was getting NIC drivers at the time and must have pasted the incorrect model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there's a good chance you won't be able to use both the on-board and the video card at the same time.  YMMV.

Having said that, try reinstalling the on-board drivers.

The "Intel 82579LM" is actually the integrated Network adapter, and not the video. Your on-board video is the [Intel HD 2000](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/hd-graphics/hd-graphics-developer.html).

Download the latest video drivers from either HP, or directly from Intel.

Uninstall the Intel video drivers, disable or remove the video card, reboot into Windows, and let it detect the on-board video again.  Give it the driver you downloaded.

Comment: I was unable to run both simultaneously. My solution was to use a USB video card I had here to add another monitor. I am also getting a DVI to 2xVGA splitter.